# How to hide react sweetalert popup on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I have this code in my app.

```
MySwal.fire({
      html: (
        <div>
          <img src={avatar} style={{ width: 100 }} />
          <h3>{errText}</h3>
        </div>
      ),
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: loginText,
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
      if (isConfirm) onConfirm();
    });
```

Here's onConfirm function:

```
const onConfirm = () => {
    setRedirect({ status: true, href: "/login" });
  };
```

And here's the return part:

```
return redirect.status ? <Redirect to={redirect.href} /> : null;
```

At first everything goes okay, it redirects on login page but sweetalert popup stays there. 
When i click confirm button second time, popup disappears.

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox.io with example code?

Comment: no it's a big project

Comment: Don't put all your code, just create two pages and a sweetlalert and then route from one page to another on confirm